# MatPlotLib with Sublime Text 2 on OSX

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to use matplotlib from my Sublime Text 2 directly via the build command.

Does anybody know how I accomplish that? I'm really confused about the whole multiple python installations/environments. Google didn't help.

My python is installed via homebrew and in my terminal (which uses brew python), I have no problem importing matplotlib from there. But Sublime Text shows me an import Error (No module named matplotlib.pyplot).
I have installed Matplotlib via EPD free. The main matplotlib .dmg installer refused to install it on my disk, because no system version 2.7 was found. I have given up to understand the whole thing. I just want it to work.

And, I have to say, for every bit of joy python brings with it, the whole thing with installations and versions and path, environments is a real hassle.

Beneath a help for this specific problem I would appreciate any helpful link to understand and this environment mess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and the following fix worked for me:

**1 -** `Open Sublime Text 2` -> `Preferences` -> `Browse Packages`

**2 -** Go to the Python folder, select file `Python.sublime-build`

**3 -** Replace the existing `cmd` line for this one:

> "cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python", "$file"],

Then click <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and your script with `matplotlib` stuff will work.